# how can i remove blank checkbox item from checkbox list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I remove blank items from a checkbox list in asp.net? I use this code but don't know what write inside the if body to remove that item

```
        foreach (ListItem item in chkdisease.Items)
        {

            if (item.ToString() == "")
            {

            }

          }
```

Comment: `if(item.ToString().length() > 0) { } `

Comment: `IsNullOrEmpty(item.ToString())`

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599643/remove-items-from-a-checkbox-list. You can get ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code and use this :

```
for(int i=0; i<chkdisease.Items.Count; i++){
    if(chkdisease.Items[i].Text.ToString() == "")
        chkdisease.Items.Remove(chkdisease.Items[i]);
}
```

As i am not sure what problem are you facing with the above code, i would suggest you to fix the issue in back-end rather front-end. As you are filling the checkboxlist from database, just use a query like below for your checkboxlist datasource :

```
select disease from yourtable where disease is not null and disease<>''
```

Comment: not working..actually i filled checkboxlist from database. So when i run the code on screen there is also a blank checkbox in list. and i want to remove it

Comment: Did you debug the above code? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: yes i debug there is no error. don't know why it is giving one empty checkbox on user interface

Comment: Try my second suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if(chkdisease.Items.Any()) {
  foreach (ListItem item in chkdisease.Items.Where(c=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.ToString())))
    {
      //your code here
    }
 }
```